# android refresh listview from broadcastreceiver

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-listview

My app contains a `ListView` in an activity and a `BroadcastReceiver`. I would like my `Broadcastreceiver` to refresh the `ListView` when it is triggered. My receiver puts content into an sqlite DB and my `listview` displays the content of that DB.

Activity with ListView:

```
lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.conversation);
lv.setSelection(lv.getCount()-1);
lv.setAdapter(new mAdapter(this, srsList, messagesList, timesList, numbersList, idList));
registerForContextMenu(lv);
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
//values.put(Messages.KEY_ID, i1);
values.put(Messages.KEY_sr, "r");
values.put(Messages.KEY_message, message);
values.put(Messages.KEY_time, datetime);
values.put(Messages.KEY_number, sen);
// Inserting Row
long student_Id = db.insert(Messages.TABLE, null, values);
db.close(); // Closing database connection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a BroadcastReciever in your activity which holds the adapter and notify that the the adapter should be refreshed :

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Extract data included in the Intent
        // String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        if (mAdapter!= null) {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

Reigester this BroadcastReciever in onResume:

```
this.registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("some_unique_name"));
```

And unregiester onPause:

```
this.unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
```

In your BroadcastReciever just use:

```
private void updateYourActivity(Context context) {

    Intent intent = new Intent("some_unique_name");

    // put whatever data you want to send, if any
    // intent.putExtra("message", message);

    // send broadcast
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```